# How to push values to an object from inside a map function when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, json

How can we push values to an object from inside a map function and return that single object. I have string comparison condition inside the map function. I tried using `Object.assign` but it returns an array with multiple object inside that array. Instead of this multiple object I'm expecting a single object inside an array.

Map function

```
let arrayObj = arrayToTraverse.map(function(item) {
    var myObj = {};
    if(item.inputvalue === 'Name'){
        Object.assign(myObj, {name: item.value});
    } else if (item.inputvalue === 'Email'){
        Object.assign(organizerInfo, {email: item.value});
    } else if (item.inputvalue === 'Company'){
        Object.assign(organizerInfo, {company: item.value});
    }
    return myObj;
});
console.log("The array object is", arrayObj)
```

This return the array of objects as follows

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tom"
  },
  {
    "email": "tom@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "company": "ABC"
  }
]
```

But The array I'm expecting is

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "email": "tom@abc.com",
    "company": "ABC"
  }
]

// or
[
   "returned": {
      "name": "Tom",
      "email": "tom@abc.com",
      "company": "ABC"
   }
]
```

An example of arrayToTraverse can be considered as following

```
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "inputvalue": "Name",
      "value": "Tom",
      "type": "Short Text"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "inputvalue": "Email",
      "value": "tom@abc.com",
      "type": "Email ID"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "inputvalue": "Company",
      "value": "Google",
      "type": "Long Text"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: please provide the arrayToTraverse in the code

Comment: @MajiD the example of arrayToTraverse is given after editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you're trying to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) an array to a single object, not `map` one array to another.

```js
var arrayToTraverse = [
   {inputvalue:"Name",value:"Tom"},
   {inputvalue:"Email",value:"tom@abc.com"},
   {inputvalue:"Company",value:"ABC"},
   {inputvalue:"Foo",value:"Bar"} // wont show up
];

var valuesRequired = ["Name","Email","Company"];

var result = arrayToTraverse.reduce( (acc, item) => {
    if(valuesRequired.includes(item.inputvalue))
      acc[item.inputvalue.toLowerCase()] = item.value;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Edit: Added lookup array for required fields.

Comment: Hi @Jamiec arrayToTraverse will be a very big Array of objects so I'm basically not only trying to reduce. The map function is important because of the `if condintion`. The values in the object's key are added because of the map function and the condition used.

Comment: @LalasM you can do the exact same `if` logic inside the `reduce`. If you show the contents of `arrayToTraverse` it is easier to answer. If its big you could cut it down to show the relevant info

Comment: the example of arrayToTraverse is given after editing the question

Comment: @LalasM right, given that I dont understand where the problem lies? Is it that there are more values in `arrayToTraverse` that you don't want?

Comment: @Jamiac the arrayToTraverse is dynamic and it can grow

Comment: And you only want 3 values? Name, Email, Company?

Comment: Yes  exactly .. BTW I'm trying the example you had provided and update you soon ..

Comment: I saw the update and that gave me the hint... Thanks.. I can give +1 to your answer. In fact from your answer please remove the `var arrayToTraverse` declaration as we don't need to re declare or change that array. Then I can make it as accepted answer

Comment: @LalasM that is just there to make my answer runnable, but yes it will work exactly the same with your input!